# Sequelize - TypeError: Usuarios.findAll(...).them is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, express, sequelize.js

Hola y gracias a todos por vuestras respuestas y comentarios de antemano, me he visto en la necesidad de integrar MySql en una aplicación de NodeJS, estoy utilizando Sequelize como ORM y tengo el siguiente problema:

[image: error]
A continuación adjunto tanto el modelo como el método en el que lo utilizo:

**Modelo**

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const sequelize = require('../mysqlDatabase');

const Usuarios = sequelize.define('usuarios', {
    nombre: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    apellido: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    correo: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    pass: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    rol: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
});

module.exports = Usuarios;
```

**Controlador de usuarios** (aquí es en principio donde me marca el problema)

```
'use strict'

const console = require('colorful-console-logger');  
const Usuarios = require('../models/usuarios');

var controller = {

    register: function(req, res){

        const body = req.body;
        const correo = body.correo;

        Usuarios.findAll({
            where: {
              correo: correo
            }
        })
        .them(duplicateuser => {
            console.warn("Server - WARN", "El usuario ya estaba registrado en la base de datos", duplicateuser);
            return res.status(300).send({
                msg: "Ya existe un usuario con este correo electronico"
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("sequelize - ERR", "Ocurrio un error inesperado mientras se intentaba buscar un usuario con el mismo correo que el introducido, el error se encuentra detallado a continuación", err)
        })
    }
}

module.exports = controller
```

He verificado tanto las rutas de los archivos como la conexión con mi base de datos y en principio esta todo correcto. Espero que me puedan ayudar y disculpen si el error es muy obvio ya que es la primera vez que utilizo este ORM

Comment: Es una errata, el método a llamar debería ser `.then`y no `them`

Comment: Te debo una Pablo muchisimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como me comenta el señor Pablo Lozano en un comentario anterior se trata de una errata en mi código y basta con cambiar .them() or .then().